# The Art and Science of Java Chapter 3, Exercise 2

Tags: java

I would like to know if this is the best way to solve the Chapter 3, exercise 2.

> Exercise 2: Write a program that reads in two numbers: an account balance and an annual
>   interest rate expressed as a percentage. Your program should then display the
>   new balance after a year. There are no deposits or withdrawals - just the
>   interest payment. Your program should be able to re produce the following
>   sample run:
>
> Interest calculation program
>   Enter starting balance: 6000
>   Enter annual interest rate: 4.25
>   Balance after one year = 6255.0

Possible Solution:

```
/* Interest.java
 * -------------------------------
 * Program reads two numbers and 
 * adds the interest rate. 
 */

import acm.program.*;

public class Interest extends ConsoleProgram{

    public void run(){
        int sBalance = readInt("Enter Balance: ");
        Double iRate = readDouble("Enter interest rate: ");
        Double yBalance = sBalance + (sBalance * (iRate / 100));
        println("The balance after one year = " + yBalance);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, how would you solve it if you can't use anything from `acm.program.*`? I'm almost positive that's not a standard library.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: Btw, what is Chapter 3, exercisee 2? @MAO

Comment: @DennisMeng: it's likely a library that his class is required to use.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If that's actually the case, then it's worth a clarification from the poster though.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code and it works. 
@Dennis Meng acm.program.* is a library Stanford uses to facilitate teaching java. It makes debugging a lot easier since a console window pops out and it's interactive rather than using the console that might be a bit scarier for beginners

Comment: Good to know. I'll keep that in mind if I ever run into it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
import acm.program.*;


public class CHP3_Exercise2And3 extends ConsoleProgram {

public void run() {
      println("Interest calculation program");
      double Starting_Balance = readDouble("Enter starting balance: ");
      double Annual_Interest_Rate = readDouble("Enter annual interest rate: ");
      double Operation_Year1 = ((Starting_Balance * Annual_Interest_Rate)/100)+Starting_Balance;
      double Operation_Year2 = ((Operation_Year1 * Annual_Interest_Rate)/100)+Operation_Year1;
      println("Balance after one year = " + Operation_Year1);
      println("Balance after two years = " + Operation_Year2);
    }
}
```